# How to set the resolution in text consoles using Nvidia proprietary driver, without using GRUB

Tags: linux, nvidia, console, resolution, refind

I just installed an Nvidia GPU, with the properitery Nvidia drivers, for better speed & support.

The text console's resolution feels very small compared to the actual resolution of 1920x1080. I've googled around and the only thing I've found is using GRUB with:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

I'm using rEFInd and Btrfs, and would prefer to not use GRUB at all.

So is there any other way to change the text console's resolution?

I've tried including `resolution 1920 1080` and `resolution 0` in `/etc/refind.d/refind.conf`, with no effect. The `vga=ask` kernel option also has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Googling I found [tty resolution (nvidia, PSA-ish?) : archlinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/86lqc5/tty_resolution_nvidia_psaish/).

The setting `use_graphics_for linux` in `/etc/refind.d/refind.conf` does indeed give a native resolution.

The issue is that it hides kernel parameters. Any alternative solution that shows the kernel parameters too would be ideal.